# How to Display Created By Field in InfoPath AND Sharepoint list with multiple values?

Tags: infopath, column, default

The article **"How to Display Created By Field in InfoPath"** seemed to work for a user on this forum. However, my needs are slightly different.  I'm trying to create a list with the entry form showing the `created by` field.  This field has several values that it captures, including name, email and phone.

I'd like to display all 3 in my list and if possible, in my entry form (add new item, voila, this info in the popup auto populates).

I've been told this isn't possible to use a calculated field and concatenate like in excel.  I can see/add the `created by` field in infopath, however, i can't seem to get it pre-populate (display automatically) and although it shows on the list view, I can't get name, email and phone to display on the list, only one name OR email OR phone.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not seeing values on a *New Item* form for the **Created By** field because the item isn't created yet, so there are no creator. I replicated the issue, and the value only appear on *"Edit"/"View"* form.

For the additional information on the creator user, you could access the *User Profile Web Service* (located in http://site/_vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx) and the operation **"GetUserProfileByName"** to access the properties of the Current User and then store the results in custom fields in InfoPath. Just add a rule to make sure this values aren't overwritten, and you are good to go.

It is a more customized approach, but I think the results will satisfy your needs. One thing I think you will lose if you don't use the field for Person/Group is the presence indicator, in case your SharePoint environment is connect to Exchange and Lync.

If you want to try this approach, here is an article that helped me in the past, and I can attest it works:
http://www.qdoscc.com/blog/how-automatically-retrieve-current-username-infopath-sharepoint-list-form